# How to set a value in a third column depending on values in two other columns

Tags: python

I have a dataframe which looks like the below.

```
Key|Direction
:--|-------: 
x  | Sell
x  | Buy
x  | BUY
y  | Sell
y  | Sell
y  | Sell
Z  | Buy
Z  | Buy
a  | Buy
a  | Sell
```

What I want to do is create a third column where for all the same keys if there is a buy and a sell for that key the third column will say yes. If not it just says no. I was playing around with groupby but I finding it hard to re-assign the values back into the data frame. This is what I want the final column to look like

```
Key|Direction |Cross
:--|-------   |------
x  | Sell     | yes
x  | Buy      | yes
x  | BUY      | yes
y  | Sell     | no
y  | Sell     | no
y  | Sell     | no
Z  | Buy      | no 
Z  | Buy      | no
a  | Buy      | yes
a  | Sell     | yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with comparing `set`s and last [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`:

```
d = {True:'yes', False:'no'}
df['Cross'] = df.groupby('Key')['Direction'] \
                .transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(['Buy','Sell'])).map(d)
print (df)
  Key Direction Cross
0   x      Sell   yes
1   x       Buy   yes
2   x       Buy   yes
3   y      Sell    no
4   y      Sell    no
5   y      Sell    no
6   Z       Buy    no
7   Z       Buy    no
8   a       Buy   yes
9   a      Sell   yes
```

Another solution with create `Series` of `set`s, [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` for new column, compare with [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`) and last map by `dict`:

```
d = {True:'yes', False:'no'}
s = df.groupby('Key')['Direction'].apply(set)
df['Cross'] = df['Key'].map(s).eq(set(['Buy','Sell'])).map(d)
print (df)
  Key Direction Cross
0   x      Sell   yes
1   x       Buy   yes
2   x       Buy   yes
3   y      Sell    no
4   y      Sell    no
5   y      Sell    no
6   Z       Buy    no
7   Z       Buy    no
8   a       Buy   yes
9   a      Sell   yes
```

---

Similar solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
s = df.groupby('Key')['Direction'].apply(set)
df['Cross'] = np.where(df['Key'].map(s).eq(set(['Buy','Sell'])), 'yes', 'no')
print (df)
  Key Direction Cross
0   x      Sell   yes
1   x       Buy   yes
2   x       Buy   yes
3   y      Sell    no
4   y      Sell    no
5   y      Sell    no
6   Z       Buy    no
7   Z       Buy    no
8   a       Buy   yes
9   a      Sell   yes
```

Comment: This is great thanks! I was trying to use np.where as well but wasnt doing it properly so this is fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) first:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Key',sort=False)['Direction'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
print(df1)
```

Note that you need to set sort to False

df1 looks like:

```
  Key         Direction
0   x    Sell, Buy, Buy
1   y  Sell, Sell, Sell
2   Z          Buy, Buy
3   a         Buy, Sell
```

then you just create your new column with the correct number of 'yes' or 'no' depending on how many keys you have.

Note that we use [split](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) to know how many directions there are for a single key

```
cross=[]
for row in df1.index:
    elem = df1.ix[row,'Direction']

    if Sell in elem and Buy in elem:
        for i in range(len(elem.split(','))):
            cross.append('yes')
    else:
        for i in range(len(elem.split(','))):
            cross.append('no')

df['Cross'] = pd.Series(cross)
print(df)
```

output:

```
  Key Direction Cross
0   x      Sell   yes
1   x       Buy   yes
2   x       Buy   yes
3   y      Sell    no
4   y      Sell    no
5   y      Sell    no
6   Z       Buy    no
7   Z       Buy    no
8   a       Buy   yes
9   a      Sell   yes
```

PS:
while creating the dataframe in your examples i added this to go faster, so please take that in consideration:

```
Sell='Sell'
Buy='Buy'
```